# Having Error while working with Retrofit lib. JsonSyntaxException

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit, themoviedb-api

I am practising with retrofit and i am having an error as 

**`com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was NUMBER at line 1 column 31 path $.total_results`**

I am using this api **https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=########################**

here is my code

**`MainActivity.java`**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String Tag=MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private static final String APIKEY="###########################";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final ProgressDialog pDialog= new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();
    final RecyclerView recyclerView =(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerMovie);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    ApiInterface apiService= ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<MovieResponse> call =apiService.getTopRatedMovie(APIKEY);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<MovieResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MovieResponse> call, Response<MovieResponse> response) {
            List<Movie> movies=response.body().getResults();
            Log.d(Tag, "Numbers Of Movies Received"+ movies.size());
            MovieAdapter adapter =new MovieAdapter(movies,R.layout.list_item_movies,getApplicationContext());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            pDialog.dismiss();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MovieResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(Tag,"Error:-"+t.toString());
            pDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Oops Error...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}}
```

**`Movie.java`**

```
public class Movie {

    @SerializedName("poster_path")
    @Expose
    private String posterPath;

    @SerializedName("adult")
    @Expose
    private boolean adult;

    @SerializedName("overview")
    @Expose
    private String overview;

    @SerializedName("release_date")
    @Expose
    private String releaseDate;

    @SerializedName("genre_ids")
    @Expose
    private List<Integer> genreIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;

    @SerializedName("original_title")
    @Expose
    private String originalTitle;

    @SerializedName("original_language")
    @Expose
    private String originalLanguage;

    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;

    @SerializedName("backdrop_path")
    @Expose
    private String backdropPath;

    @SerializedName("popularity")
    @Expose
    private Double popularity;

    @SerializedName("vote_count")
    @Expose
    private Integer voteCount;

    @SerializedName("video")
    @Expose
    private Boolean video;

    @SerializedName("vote_average")
    @Expose
    private Double voteAverage;


    public Movie(String posterPath, boolean adult, String overview, String releaseDate, List<Integer> genreIds, Integer id, String originalTitle, String originalLanguage, String title, String backdropPath, Double popularity, Integer voteCount, Boolean video, Double voteAverage) {
            this.posterPath = posterPath;
            this.adult = adult;
            this.overview = overview;
            this.genreIds = genreIds;
            this.backdropPath = backdropPath;
            this.id=id;
            this.originalLanguage=originalLanguage;
            this.originalTitle=originalTitle;
            this.releaseDate=releaseDate;
            this.title=title;
            this.video=video;
            this.voteAverage=voteAverage;
            this.voteCount=voteCount;
            this.popularity=popularity;
    }
    //getter and setter methods }
```

**`MovieResponse.java`**

```
public class MovieResponse {

@SerializedName("page")
@Expose
private int page;

@SerializedName("results")
@Expose
private List<Movie> results;

@SerializedName("total_pages")
@Expose
private int total_pages;

@SerializedName("total_results")
@Expose
private List<Movie> total_results;
//getter and setter methods}
```

**`ApiClient.java`**

```
public class ApiClient {

public static final String Base_URl="http://api.themoviedb.org/3/";
public static Retrofit retrofit=null;

public static Retrofit getClient(){
    if(retrofit==null){
        retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Base_URl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}}
```

**`ApiInterface.java`**

`public interface ApiInterface{`

```
@GET("movie/top_rated")
Call<MovieResponse> getTopRatedMovie(@Query("api_key") String apiKey);

@GET("movie/{id}")
Call<MovieResponse> getMovieDetails(@Path("id") int id, @Query("api_key") String apiKey);
```

`}`

Please Give me the solution...

Comment: Where do you have this error?

Comment: In Movie.java the "genreIds" don't have a proper class assigned, it is Integer type, but it should be Bean class instead. Try this and do let me know.

Comment: when I tries ur api it returns response as Movie object and not like MovieResponse, it may be the reason why it shows a json exeption

Comment: I suggest to create a new Response classes using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: Your variable's serialized name is not matching with the response, for example it is 'genres' and not 'genre_ids'

Comment: Thanks for your help... @RakshitNawani and other all

Comment: Please, show JSON you're trying to parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you created wrong object

```
@SerializedName("total_results")
@Expose
private List<Movie> total_results;
```

change to

```
   @SerializedName("total_results")
   @Expose
   private Int total_results;
```

because as per your error it should be number of result and you created List so it will ask for ARRAY only.

If I am wrong then please copy your response and take pojo class from 
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: @AnkitBhalodiya: if you found solution is work for you then please accept as Answer.

Comment: @AnkitBhalodiya: In my solution you can see Right Icon is there just click on It, so it is consider as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look closely to your `Movie.java` POJO, especially to this field:

```
@SerializedName("genre_ids")
@Expose
private List<Integer> genreIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

...which has type of List of Integers. In the JSON that you've provided this array contains an Objects instead of Integer ids. You can represent this object like this:

```
public class Genre {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private int id;

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
}
```

Furthermore, the actual name of this array is `genres` (not the `genres_ids`). So, to avoid the parsing error the only thing you need is to change the field above to this:

```
@SerializedName("genres")
@Expose
private List<Genre> genres = new ArrayList< Genre >();
```

Happy coding! ;)